# Android Wallpaper application Save Button?

Tags: android, button, wallpaper

Im making an wallpaper app with tons of images
and i have set as wallpaper button and share but i don't know how to program a button for save image to sdcard or internal.
Could someone help me?
I tried doing it once but i screwed up my whole project.